# .html() to Not Encode the Passed Value

Tags: jquery, html, encoding

I need to keep each character passed to `.html()` as is i.e. not encoded. For example, `.html('>')` to save the less-than character as `>`, not `&lt;`. How would I do this? Ideally, the solution would *apply* to all "special" characters e.g. `<`, `&`, etc.

```
<h1 id="my-title"></h1>

// JavaScript / jQuery code.
$('#my-title').html('>');
...
...
// Somewhere else in the code, I need to retrieve the value back by calling
// var v = $('#my-title').html();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.html()` use `.text()` to save and retrieve the value.

```
$('#my-title').text('>');
var v = $('#my-title').text();

alert( v );   // alerts >
```

Note that you need to use `.text()` for saving the value as well. There's a reason why `<` and `>` become encoded...

Comment: The `html()` function makes it encoded. try this: `$('#my-title').text('>');
var v = $('#my-title').html();`

Comment: Sure, but if you have `$('#my-title').html('<test>'); var v = $('#my-title').text();` it shows nothing because it thinks `<test>` is a tag. http://jsfiddle.net/HtbG5/2/

Answer (score 2):

Use `text()` instead of `html()`

```
var v = $('#my-title').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

`text` won't encode the value:

```
$('#my-title').html('>');
alert($('#my-title').text() + ' not encoded');
alert($('#my-title').html() + ' encoded');
​
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HtbG5/)

Comment: This works when the value is e.g. `>`, but, as pointed out by @Juhana, it'd fail when the value is e.g. `<test>`. Thanks for jsFiddle, though (+1).